# Olá, boa noite! Estou precisando de ajuda para resolver exercício de array em javascript. Sou Iniciante, agradeço toda ajuda

Tags: javascript

Elaborar um programa que leia duas matrizes A e B de uma dimensão com seis elementos. A matriz A deve aceitar apenas a entrada de valores pares, enquanto a matriz B deve aceitar apenas entrada de valores impares. A entrada das matrizes deve ser validada pelo programa. Construir a matriz C que seja o resultado da junção das matrizes A e B, de modo que a matriz C contenha 12 elementos. Apresentar os elementos da matriz C.

```
console.log('Exercício 06')
var matriz06A = [];
var matriz06B = [];
var matriz06C = [];
function fpares (num){
    n = num;
    if (n % 2 == 0){
        return (n);
    }
}

function fimpares (num){
    n = num;
    if (n % 2 == 1){
        return (n);
    }
}


function felementosA (){
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        matriz06A.push(fpares(Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 +1)))
        matriz06A = matriz06A.filter(function(item){
            return item != null
        })
    }
return matriz06A;        
}

function felementosB (){
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        matriz06B.push(fimpares(Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 +1)));
        matriz06B = matriz06B.filter(function(item){
            return item != null
        })
    }
return matriz06B;        
}

felementosA();
felementosB();
matriz06C = matriz06A.concat(matriz06B);
console.log('Matriz A: '+matriz06A); //este vetor deve possuir 6 elemento
console.log('Matriz B: '+matriz06B);
console.log('Matriz C: '+matriz06C);
console.log(`A matriz C possui ${matriz06C.length} elementos.`)
```

Comment: Olá, reserve um minuto do seu tempo para ler sobre [Como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas), irá te ajudar a melhorar o corpo de suas perguntas e a obter respostas de maneira mais fácil.

Comment: Olá Léo, bom dia! Obrigado pela dica com relação às boas práticas.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Por que você está gerando a matriz? Não é para o usuário entrar as matrizes?

```js
(function () {
  function getValue(title) {
    return window.prompt(title);
  }
  
  function getMatrix(name, length, breakPredicate) {
    var M = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      var element = 0;
      do {
        element = getValue("Matriz " + name + ", elemento " + i + 
          " (entre número inteiro de 32 bits não-negativo):");
      } while (element === null 
               || !/^\d{1,10}$/.test(element)
               || element.trim() === ''
               || isNaN((element = +element))
               || element < 0 
               || !breakPredicate(element));
      M.push(element);
    }
    return M;
  }
  
  var A = getMatrix("A", 6, function(x) { return x % 2 === 0; });
  var B = getMatrix("B", 6, function(x) { return x % 2 !== 0; });
  var C = A.concat(B);
  
  alert("A matriz C é " + JSON.stringify(C));
})();
```

Comment: Olá, Marcelo, bom dia!

Comment: Marcelo, estou gerando valores aleatórios para a matriz, afim de agilizar o processo de obtenção dos valores para a matriz. Agradeço o retorno, vou tentar resolver o exercício.

Comment: Consegui fazer o exercício. Muito Grato!!